# Let $P$ be the statement: "For all sets $A$, $B$ and $C$, if $A ⊆ B\cup C$ then $A-B=\emptyset$. Is $P$ true? Prove your answer.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I drew a Venn diagram and know that this statement is false I just don't know how to prove it. I don't need hints I really need to know the full proof.

Is the converse true or false? Proof?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the statement is false, then you need just one example, not a proof.

Comment: A counter example *is* a proof of the falsity of the statement.

Comment: Hint for both parts: $A - B = \emptyset$ is equivalent to $A \subseteq B$.  (Yes, I did see your request for a full solution, but hints can never hurt, and there's still a chance they might help you solve it yourself, which would be the best outcome in my opinion.)

Comment: If you want to use something like Venn diagrams, why not consider the sets, $$A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\leq\frac{1}{4}\}\\ B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\leq 1\}\\ C=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:(x-5)^2+(y-5)^2\leq 1\}$$.

Answer (score 1):

It is false. Take $B = \{1\}$ , $C = \{2,3\}$ and $A = \{2,3\}$. Then $A-B = \{2,3\}$.

We can search for a missing condition. Let's say "For all sets $A$,$B$ and $C$, if $A \subseteq (B \cup C)$ then $A-B = \emptyset$." Then, $A \subseteq B$ and $C-B = \emptyset$. So, if we take $C \cup B$, new $P$ is correct.